# How to code page in Page Object Model for easier debugging of Protractor tests?

Tags: typescript, debugging, protractor, pageobjects

**Preface**

I want to prepare easy to maintain and debug code for e2e testing using Page Object Model.

**What I do**

When I start to prepare the [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org) end 2 end tests, I try to prepare code in [Page Object Model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) by performing following steps:

1. Open page that I am going to test in web browser,
2. Open [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (F12),
3. Using [inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) tool familiarize with the DOM of the
   page, looking at ID's, classes names and CSS Selectors for the elements that I want to use for Page Object Model,
4. start coding in such a way that elements depends on the
   previously defined ones. In particular, I try to divide my code in different classes.

Let me provide a simplified example of such code mentioned in point 4:

```
class genericPageWithTable {

    get Frame1() {
        return element(by.id('someId'));
        }

    get Table1() {
        return this.Frame1.element(by.tagName('table'));
        }
}

class specificTable extends genericPageWithTable {

    get specificElement {
        return this.Table1.element(by.className('specificElement'));
        }
}
```

and I wrote simple test with following example assertion:

```
expect(specificElement.getText()).toBe('someString');
```

and there's where my frustration begins...

Test fails, beacause `undefined` has no getText()...

**Problem**

I don't know which element was undefined, which of my methods returned no element. I don't know if I could trust any of my methods.

so I'm running `protractor --elementExplorer` and try to verify if I wrote properly each of my locators...
in elementExplorer it works, so I'm starting to adding `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(...))` conditions... but now the error message provides me information that undefined doesn't contain 'isPresent' method.
So I'm starting to add `async` and `await`, but in many cases it is still difficult to find where the undefined is returned...

adding break points and trying to debug also confuses me in many cases, because the flow is in some way unexpected.

---

**Questions**

Could you please tell me:

1. How should I prepare code for Page Object Model, so that it will be easier to maintain and debug, so that I will be sure that my methods really returns something? Are there better ways than using developer tools in browser and coding based on what I see in HTML?
2. What is a better way to ensure that my code for Page Object Model is correct? Obviously I could try to write test for each method/property, but I don't want to confuse those who will read the test output (and expect the results from business perspective)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using developer tools or the actual HTML in the project are good approaches.
2. If you are going to write methods to get/perform everything on every page you will spend a lot time. The way I do it is I create methods as I am writing my tests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my big concern is that coding this way I'm not 100% sure whether correct elements will be returned by my methods. What do you think about usage of some auto-generation tools, such as: https://github.com/pageobject-io/pageobject-generator ?

Comment: Personally I have never used it and feel it could be necessary.

What I used to do when I was new with protractor was use `document.querySelector()` with the selectors I'd use in the page object in the browser console. That way I can see what I will get. 
I also used to console log `getText()` in my tests, again to check that the I am getting the correct element.

Comment: Check this- [page-object-protractor](https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2019/08/01/implementing-page-object-model-using-protractor-and-typescript/)